# Is it better to use many event delegation with jQuery or just on and use if inside?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, performance

I'm working on a new website based on jquery and i was wondering which is the best option regarding performance :

**Option 1:**

```
$("body").on("click",".label-type1",function(){...});
$("body").on("click",".label-type2",function(){...});
....
```

**Option 2:**

```
$("body").on("click","label",function(){
     if($(this).hasClass("label-type1"){
        ...
     }else if($(this).hasClass("label-type2"){
        ...
     }});
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: why you can not manage same `class` for all these `label` elements if you have same action.

Comment: no it's not the same action everyone of them has a different function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Between these two options, you should find the performance difference fairly negligible since both handlers are going through a similar process to filter by the labels you are trying to target.

See jQuery source code for events and matching selectors:

https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js#L395

https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/2d4f53416e5f74fa98e0c1d66b6f3c285a12f0ce/src/selector-native.js#L143

And a related performance test for native `matchesSelector()`:

https://jsperf.com/matchesselector-performance

Option 1 will have more event handlers created of course, which means more memory usage. But that doesn't necessarily mean it's going to impact performance until you scale drastically. That being said, option 1 should perform slightly better at a small scale since it's not going through additional `hasClass` conditions inside the handlers. But option 2 is much better if you're concerned about keeping memory footprint low, and may be easier to organize since you can create a helper function to handle each case in a separate place in your code.